# How can I embed angular directive style within the js code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a project written in angular 1.5 Until I upgrade to angular 2, I would like to reach a state where I write something like

```
angular.module(..).directive('name', () => {
     return {
         restrict: 'A', 
         template: `
             <div> ... some template... </div>
         `,
         style: `// this is what I am missing
             div{
                // some css
             }
         `, 
         controller: function($scope){ ... }   
     }
})
```

The only piece I am missing is the style part. How can I get that? Is it supported in angular 1.x? Is there a tool that can help me get this functionality?

To make it clear - I am not asking about scoped css.
I don't care that these rules will be global or not.
I just want to be able to write the css next to the template and the controller.

So if you know about a tool like babel for example that can extract the style part to a css/scss file, that would qualify.
It can even be a general solution that I can use for this scenario.

Comment: how about putting your css inside `<style>` tag inside your template?

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/angularjs/comments/4ek4j2/ask_reddit_css_scoping_with_angular_15_components/#form-t1_d20yr3yfb5)

> To my knowledge, there is no way to do that "automatically". Personally when i create a component i just give a specific ID / class to the top element, and restrict the component's CSS to that element.
>
> Example: my-component.html

```
<div class="my-component-wrapper">
 ....
 </div>
```

> my-component.scss

```
.my-component-wrapper {
   // style that applies only to my component
}
```

A `style` property on an angular 1.5 component is not supported or it'd have been mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)

Comment: your answer is about scoping.. I am asking about code organization. I just want my code to be in the same file. for scoping I can (and I already do) use your suggestion.

Comment: @guymograbi You're asking how to have a css style apply only to a component, which this answer solves. A `style` property on an angular 1.5 component is not supported or it would have been mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)

Comment: I am trying to clarify my question. I did not write the word 'apply' anywhere.. I just want the 'style' to be next to the 'template' and the 'controller'.

Comment: @guymograbi I'm not sure what your ultimate goal is here. You want to have the `style` tag next to `template` and `controller` like in Angular 2. The purpose of that tag in Angular 2 is so that your css style will only apply to that particular component, but now you're saying that that's not what you want?

Comment: right, I just want the organized in a single file. - not necessarily a 'style' property.. just have the javascript, html and css in a single file. it's very easy.